# How to interpret the one-form "$dx$" on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ have the usual coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and $S^2$ be the unit sphere. I was recently asked to "consider" the one-form $\alpha=xdy-ydx$ on the sphere, but I don't really know what is meant. What is "$dx$" on the sphere? Perhaps if I pull back the function "$x$" to the sphere and take the differential of it, this is what is meant? Or I pull back the one-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the sphere?

Comment: For practice, what is the $1$-form $\alpha = x\,dx + y\,dy+ z\,dz$ on the unit sphere?

Answer (score 2):

The sphere $S^2$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can identify $T_xS^2$ to a subspace of $T_x\mathbb{R}^3$, a form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be restricted to $S^2$.

Comment: Sorry Tsemo, when you say "a form restricted to $S^2$" you mean, take the form $\alpha$ but only evaluate it on elements of $T_x(S^2)$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, since $T_xS^2\subset T_x\mathbb{R}^3$.